# How to change the Status Bar color in Flutter when we are using an AppBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I know we can change the Status Bar using:

- [`SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html)
- [`AnnotatedRegion`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnnotatedRegion-class.html)

But the docs mention the `AppBar` will set the Status Bar color automatically, so the question I have is, how do I set the Status Bar color, when I have an `AppBar` in place, but I want to define a specific color myself and not let the `AppBar` do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to define a specific color myself and not let the AppBar do it automatically?

Using SystemChrome will override the Appbar setting.

If you want to set the color yourself use the following function you already mentioned once or in an *initstate* function.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.yellow.shade600,
  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
));
```

This will override the Appbar setting

Comment: I tried to define it in the build function before the `AppBar`, so I guess it has to be in `initState`? I made it work placing it in the previous screen, just before it calls to navigate to the new route.

Comment: @mFeinstein Yup that seems to be it. initstate works like a charm for me and keeps the color even when navigating until changed by me manually.

Comment: I am using a `StatelessWidget` so I will keep it into the navigation, as I don't want to convert to a `StatefulWidget` just because of this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Additional Note: Status bar Icon Color

if the status bar icon not changing to dark or light mode. Make sure to add brightness in appbar.

```
appbar :Appbar (
 brightness: Brightness.light,),
```

Can be change to .dark or .light as above